# How to Set a value with words and Cells

Tags: google-sheets

Trying to make it where this function will spit out a sentience with the values within the cell. It is probably something obvious but Iv'e tried everything I know.

```html
  function Note1() {
    
   var sheet =      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    
   var Cell = sheet.getRange('D4').getValue();
     var Cell2= sheet.getRange('A9').getValue();
    
    sheet.getRange('A33').setValue('Bank average using the dates'Cell 'and' Cell2);
    
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why there're no concatenation operations?

```
sheet.getRange('A33').setValue('Bank average using the dates' + Cell + 'and' + Cell2);
```

Also, there's a menu item `Console` in `Script Editor` that contains all the output of your program. I've never got exceptions writing in GAS, but probably they're logged in that console too.